# node.js firebase returns then is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this Request method in node.js which gives me a key/value Asynchronously. I need to get this value globally but it is coming to be undefined outside the scope. to do this, I tried to implement "then" in the function but it is returning me

```
TypeError: request(...).then is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\FirebaseNotif\group.js:26:4)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)
```

my request is..

```
 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 console.log(body);
 key = body.notification_key;

 return key;

 }).then(result =>{
 console.log('my key is : ' + key); 
 });
```

Comment: .then() are for promises. The request method, as described in your question, uses callback. If you use the request library, you can actually use a promise implementation by installing another library - read more about it here https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait. Let me know if you wan't to "go the promise way" (since you could also sove it with a callback).

Comment: please can you tell me to solve it by callback?

Comment: What is `request`?  Are you sure it returns a promise?

Comment: it returns me a body which contains notification key. the whole request comes out to be asynchronous. that's why i am unable to fetch data inside it globally. my main aim is to get its data globally

Comment: it returns me this..  { notification_key: 'APA91bF5HLbSiDCpm9SLFzBVpVN8fuDVvd_xlyCnC6u20qZwZJcaOA_Qy1Qf5727N47A9CDOuotAu7HPvDgqoK3NgmqnnSFiXy47d6p7a-AyCZsv0JksH8Y' }